# Jackson depth dependent serialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to limit the data going from server to client via REST. Is it possible to change the Jackson serializer depending on the level it is at?

for example:
Level 0, do the usual. Level 1, do the serializer with less fields.

I have a custom serializer, but it is also being used on level 0.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, actually quite straightforward:

```
    JsonStreamContext jsonStreamContext = jsonGenerator.getOutputContext();
    if (jsonStreamContext.getParent() == null || jsonStreamContext.getParent().toString().equals("/")) {
        defaultSerializer.serialize(item, jsonGenerator, serializerProvider);
    } else {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("id", item.getId());
        jsonGenerator.writeStringField("name", item.getName());
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
```